# XSLT find and replace carriage returns

Tags: xslt, replace, xslt-1.0

I need to replace carriage returns from input XML.

Input as follows:

```
            <Answer>
            <Label>Notes/Comments</Label>
            <Value>Q
                            WERTYU IOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM 
                            QWERTYUIOPASDF GHJKLZXCVBNM
                            QWERTYU IOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
                            QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJ KLZXCVBNM
                            QWERTYU IOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
                            QWERTYUIOPASDFGH JKLZXCVBNM
                            QWERTYUIOPASDF GHJKLZXCVBNM
                            QWERTYUIOP ASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
                            QWERTYU IOPASDFGHJ KLZXCVBNM
                            QWERTY UIOPAS DFGHJKLZX CVBNM
                            QWERTYUIO PASDFGHJ KLZXC VBNM
                            </Value>
            <Iteration>0</Iteration>
            <DataType>TEXT</DataType>
        </Answer>
```

I'm attempting to remove carriage returns using the following function:

```
    <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace"/>
    <xsl:param name="by"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$by"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Calling it as follows:

```
        <xsl:when test="Label='Notes/Comments'">              
                        <xsl:element name="Comments">
                            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="Value" />
                                <xsl:with-param name="replace">&#xA;</xsl:with-param>
                                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'. '" />
                            </xsl:call-template>                
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
```

But so far to no success. I'm hoping it's just that the character (`&#xA;`) I'm passing in is incorrect but I can't get it working.

**UPDATE**

As it turns out in this case, removing more white-space characters than just Carriage returns was acceptable and so normalize-space() fulfils my requirements.

Comment: @empo - That actually works perfectly. Looks like I was massively over complicating the situation.

Comment: @empo: `normalize-space()` removes a lot more than just the CRs. As it hapens, @Fishcake wasn't precise in his question (or changed his mind).

Comment: @Dimitre Ultimately I wasn't precise enough, although my main concern was removing CRs there is no problem also removing leading/trailing spaces etc in this particular case.

Comment: @Fishcake: Yes, this happens sometimes and there is no problem unless the author doesn't edit their question to make it more precise and avoid readers comments about "inadequacies" in the current solutions. Please, update your question to include the text of your last comment.

Comment: @Fishcake so is your question solved with normalize-space()?

Comment: Yes normalize-space() solved my issue, question updated to reflect this.

Comment: Can someone provide an example of how normalize-space() is used to strip white space from the input XML? It's not clear in these comments, TY.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked that you don't have a `&#xD;` there besides the `&#xA;` ?