# links, xsl and why chrome concatenate a line feed (aka %0A HEX symbol)

Tags: xml, xslt, google-chrome, transform

I have a funny problem with presenting links in Chrome using XSL: every link concatenated with the HEX symbol "%0A".
so if the link is "www.google.com", it will be presented as "www.google.com%0A".
this problem only occurs in google chrome - Internet Explorer and FireFox present links correctly. 
so my question is: how do I prevent google chrome from messing with the links?
here is a sample of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="builtMathCSStatisticsXML.xsl"?>
<channel>
<item>
<title>algrbra
</title>
<type>class notes
</type>
<staff>Noga Alon
</staff>
<semester>
</semester>
<year>2011
</year>
<donor>anonymous
</donor>
<link>https://skydrive.live.com/self.aspx?path=%2f%d7%9e%d7%aa%d7%9e%d7%98%d7%99%d7%a7%d7%94%2f%d7%90%d7%9c%d7%92%d7%91%d7%a8%d7%94%20%d7%911.%d7%a9%d7%99%d7%a2%d7%95%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%9d%20%d7%95%d7%aa%d7%a8%d7%92%d7%99%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%9d.%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%92%d7%94%20%d7%90%d7%9c%d7%95%d7%9f%5e.%d7%aa%d7%a9%d7%a1%5e4%5e4%d7%96%20-%20%d7%a8%d7%95%d7%a2%d7%99%20%d7%a7%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%99%d7%9f.pdf&amp;cid=1f8a5680599afff9
</link>
</item>
...
</channel>
```

and here is the xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <head>
  <script src="sorttable.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body dir="rtl">
    <h2>Math CS and Statistics</h2>
    <table class="sortable">
    <thead>
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>course</th>
        <th>type</th>
        <th>proffesor</th>
        <th>semster</th>
        <th>year</th>
        <th>donors</th>
        <th>links</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <xsl:for-each select="channel/item">
      <xsl:sort select="title" />
      <tr onMouseOver="this.bgColor='yellow';" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='white';">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="type"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="staff"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="semester"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="donor"/></td>
        <td>
    <a target="_blank"><xsl:attribute name="href">
         <xsl:value-of select="link"/>
        </xsl:attribute>link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This behavior is according to the [XSLT 1.0 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#creating-attributes)**, and the explanation is rather tricky:

> **NOTE**:When an xsl:attribute contains a text node with a newline, then the XML output must contain a character reference. For example,
>
> ```
> <xsl:attribute name="a">x
> y</xsl:attribute>
> ```
>
> will result in the output
>
> ```
> a="x&#xA;y"
> ```
>
> (or with any equivalent character reference). The XML output cannot be
>
> ```
> a="x
> y"
> ```
>
> This is because XML 1.0 requires newline characters in attribute
>   values to be normalized into spaces but requires character references
>   to newline characters not to be normalized. The attribute values in
>   the data model represent the attribute value after normalization. If a
>   newline occurring in an attribute value in the tree were output as a
>   newline character rather than as character reference, then the
>   attribute value in the tree created by reparsing the XML would contain
>   a space not a newline, which would mean that the tree had not been
>   output correctly.

**So, if you really don't want the character entity, write**:

```
<link>string</link>
```

**and not**:

```
<link>string
</link>
```

**Alternatively, use**:

```
<xsl:attribute name="href">
 <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(link)"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

However, be aware that this will replace any group of non-leading or non-trailing whitespace characters with only a single space.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly Firefox and IE handle it differently but I think it's caused by the newline / carriage return character in your XML. I'm assuming this as `</link>` is on the line below the rest of the link.

You should be able to prevent this by using [normalize-space](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_normalize-space.html). Here's a similar question I asked which has more details in the comments. [XSLT find and replace carriage returns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7286579/108847)